# Understanding KeyNavigation.BeforeItem - qtQuick

Tags: qt, qt-quick

From: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-keynavigation.html#priority-prop

> **KeyNavigation.BeforeItem** - process the key events before normal item key processing. If the event is used for key navigation, it will be accepted and will not be passed on to the item.

Please make me understand the above quote with an example.

Comment: This just gives you the possibility to create your own handler which is called before the default event handler. If your event handler accepts the event, the default handler will not be called. For "AfterItem" handler, this will only be called if the default event handler does not accept the given event.

Comment: @SebastianLange Could you write that as a detailed "answers" so that it can be upvoted? Thanks.